# Turn off monitor on Ubuntu Server 16.10 when closing laptop lid

Tags: power-management, ubuntu-server

So I'm trying to set up a laptop as a little server, and I found that I can prevent the machine from suspending from setting HandleLidSwitch=ignore in a config file.

What I'm trying to accomplish now is turning off the display when I close the lid, as I see that it stays lit now.

I've seen some previous answers mentioning some power management packages that are not included in Ubuntu-Server, and I'd like to find a solution that doesn't need one.

That being said, if it can't be done, what package should I install and what config should I change?

Comment: Which config file?